# How many JSON requests can be made on Google Spreadsheet simultaneously?

Tags: api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

I want to make a website that will fetch data from Google spreadsheet. So, my question is, how many simultaneous requests for JSON data can Google sheets handle? I will write a script in Google sheets to automatically update data every hour in the sheet.

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think there's any limit.. not sure though

Answer (score 0):

If you are pertaining to requests limit, you may check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) about *Usage Limits*.

> This version of the Google Sheets API (v4) has a limit of `500 requests per 100 seconds per project`, and `100 requests per 100 seconds per user`. Limits for reads and writes are tracked separately. There is no daily usage limit.
>
> To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:
>
> 1. If you don't already have a [billing account](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6288653) for your project, then create one.
> 2. [Visit the Enabled APIs page of the API library](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/enabled) in the API Console, and select an API from the list.
> 3. To view and change quota-related settings, select **Quotas**. To view usage statistics, select **Usage**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did not get what is per project and per user.. can you please clarify a bit?